Remote iPhone Simulator
I have a Linux laptop and I recently purchased a Mac mini. I develop mobile applications using Flutter. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to run Flutter apps on a remote iOS/iPhone simulator from my Linux laptop. I believe it might be possible, as .NET Xamarin achieved this with Visual Studio.
Can anyone help me figure out how to do it?
